# keep only 1st instance of string in text file block

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have files with segments like this:

```
R_byK3rjAyABPDuil
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_27mvt5Z0CytgL2Q  
2007 UT H.B. 437
2007 UT H.B. 437
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_xGf2zqaMuPgAGn7
```

I don't want to sort or unique the entire file, only to make each n-tuple unique, like so:

```
R_byK3rjAyABPDuil
2007 UT H.B. 437 
R_27mvt5Z0CytgL2Q 
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_xGf2zqaMuPgAGn7
```

Any help would be great. I'm hoping there is a somewhat simple sed/awk hack for this. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a hack... `uniq` does this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ uniq file

R_byK3rjAyABPDuil
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_27mvt5Z0CytgL2Q
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_xGf2zqaMuPgAGn7
```

I'm sure this has been asked/answered here many times already.  If you want to get only the unique lines in the whole file without sorting

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' file

R_byK3rjAyABPDuil
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_27mvt5Z0CytgL2Q
R_xGf2zqaMuPgAGn7
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Poz 'R.*(\n[^R].*)?' file
```

Output:

```
R_byK3rjAyABPDuil
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_27mvt5Z0CytgL2Q 
2007 UT H.B. 437
R_xGf2zqaMuPgAGn7
```

---

From `man grep`:

> `-P`: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
>
> `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
>
> `-z`: Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline